# How to improve a pure CSS3 bouncing ball animation

Tags: css, css-animations

As part of a much bigger hybrid app project I need to get the user to select a set of four numbers by tapping on bouncing balls numbered 0 through to 9.  I don't want to lumber the app with a Physics engine just for that so I have elected to use a pure CSS3 animation.  My efforts are shown below

```css
body,html
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:black;
}
#stage{position:relative;}
.ball 
{
 position:absolute;
 width:7vw;
 height:7vw;
 border-radius:50%;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

@keyframes bounce 
{ 
 0% {transform:translateY(0);}
 95% {transform:translateY(86vh);}
 100% {transform:translateY(86vh);}
}

#ballZero
{
 background: #f45342;
 margin-left:1em;
 animation:bounce 3s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#ballOne
{
 background-color:lime;
 margin-left:calc(2em + 7vw);
 animation:bounce 2.7s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#ballTwo
{
 background-color:aqua;
 margin-left:calc(3em + 14vw);
 animation:bounce 3.2s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='matter.css'/>
  <style>
   body,html{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:arial;}
   #stage
   {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='stage'>
 <div class="ball" id='ballZero'>0</div>
 <div class='ball' id='ballOne'>1</div>
 <div class='ball' id='ballTwo'>2</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 
</html>
```

While this works the result is far from smooth and I recognize that CSS animations is far from being my strong suite.  How can I improve this animation to make the effect look more realistic - bearing in mind that in the real thing I require 10 balls?  Why do the balls not bounce just as soon as they touch the bottom desipite the `100% {transform:translateY(86vh);}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we add slightly different timing functions to the up and the down flight we get a bit more of a bounce effect - certainly on the ground bounce.

```
@keyframes bounce 
{ 
 0% {transform:translateY(0); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
 60% {transform:translateY(86vh); animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
 100% {transform:translateY(0); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
}
```

Playing around with cubic-bezier timing functions we'd probably get better results - though seems to be a bit of an experimental field.
Here's the result of applying the above functions:

```css
 body,html
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:black;
}
#stage{position:relative;}
.ball 
{
 position:absolute;
 width:7vw;
 height:7vw;
 border-radius:50%;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

@keyframes bounce 
{ 
 0% {transform:translateY(0); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
 60% {transform:translateY(86vh); animation-timing-function: ease-out;}
 100% {transform:translateY(0); animation-timing-function: ease-in;}
}

#ballZero
{
 background: #f45342;
 margin-left:1em;
 animation:bounce 3s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#ballOne
{
 background-color:lime;
 margin-left:calc(2em + 7vw);
 animation:bounce 2.7s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#ballTwo
{
 background-color:aqua;
 margin-left:calc(3em + 14vw);
 animation:bounce 3.2s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
} 
 body,html{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:arial;}
   #stage
   {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
   }
```

```html
<div id='stage'>
  <div class="ball" id='ballZero'>0</div>
  <div class='ball' id='ballOne'>1</div>
  <div class='ball' id='ballTwo'>2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice!  Much smoother animation

Answer (score 0):

```css
body,html
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
 background-color:black;
}
#stage{position:relative;}
.ball 
{
 position:absolute;
 width:7vw;
 height:7vw;
 border-radius:50%;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:center;
 align-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}

@keyframes bounce 
{ 
 0% {transform:translateY(0);}
 100% {transform:translateY(86vh);}
}

#ballZero
{
 background: #f45342;
 margin-left:1em;
 animation:bounce 3s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease-in;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#ballOne
{
 background-color:lime;
 margin-left:calc(2em + 7vw);
 animation:bounce 2.7s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease-in;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}

#ballTwo
{
 background-color:aqua;
 margin-left:calc(3em + 14vw);
 animation:bounce 3.2s;
 animation-direction:alternate;
 animation-timing-function:ease-in;
 animation-iteration-count:infinite;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='matter.css'/>
  <style>
   body,html{margin:0;padding:0;font-family:arial;}
   #stage
   {
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
   }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='stage'>
 <div class="ball" id='ballZero'>0</div>
 <div class='ball' id='ballOne'>1</div>
 <div class='ball' id='ballTwo'>2</div>
 </div>
 </body>
 
</html>
```